# How do I set a cookie?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How can I set a cookie and retrieve the cookie value in Drupal 8?

In plain PHP, I could use `setcookie('country', $country, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");`, but I think there is a better way, for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`user_cookie_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_cookie_save/8.0.x) which accepts an array of values.

```
user_cookie_save(['your_cookie' => "your_value"])
```

Creates a `Drupal.visitor.your_cookie` cookie: